# MySql & PHP - How to convert a string to DATETIME

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I have some data (insered by users) like :

1. *10-12-2010*
2. *XX-12-2010*
3. *10-XX-2010*
4. *10-12-XXXX*

(Notice that I add XX (or XXXX) when the data is not insered.)

How can I convert these **String** to **DATETIME** by using MySql syntax?

Thanks

**UPDATE**

```
$day=(is_numeric($_POST['day']) && $_POST['day'] > 0 && $_POST['day'] < 32) ? $_POST['day'] : '00';
$month=(is_numeric($_POST['month']) && $_POST['month'] > 0 && $_POST['month'] < 13) ? $_POST['month'] : '00';
$year=(is_numeric($_POST['year']) && $_POST['year'] > 1999 && $_POST['year'] < (date("Y")+1)) ? $_POST['year'] : '0000';            
$data=$year."-".$month."-".$day;
$mysqlDate=date('Y-m-d', strtotime($data));
echo $mysqlDate;
```

There is a problem : if data is *empty-12-2010" it print *2010-11-30*. Why?

Comment: You're not going to get far with missing data like that.  You can use strtotime functions, but they are not going to handle that well.  None of the built in functions are just going to guess what the missing parts are.

Comment: You need to address the real problem, that users are permitted to enter bad data - forcing them to pick dates from drop-lists is the usual way of doing this.  If you are allowing free-entry of text then you must be prepared to explode and analyse each field.  Thats doable in all but your case #3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're sure you don't want to **require** all the date fields, just fill them with zero if they don't exist, like this:

```
$month = ($_POST['month'] == '') ? '00' : $_POST['month'];
```

otherwise, if you're worried not about blank dates, but about non-standard input, you could do:

```
$month = (is_numeric($_POST['month']) && $_POST['month'] > 0 && $_POST['month'] < 13) ? $_POST['month'] : '00'
```

---

`$date = date('Y-m-d G:i:s', strtotime($_POST['dataThatUserEntered']));`

should do the trick, no?

Just make sure you validate the user input, otherwise you may find that `$date = '1970-01-01 00:00:00` if they enter something crazy.

Comment: You can't put '' into mysql, put '00' or '01' instead.

Comment: Clear ;) Thanks, but i have another trouble. Check the topic, i've added the trouble

Answer (score 2):

In MySQL's syntax you can use the function `STR_TO_DATE()`:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date

```
mysql> SELECT STR_TO_DATE('01,5,2013','%d,%m,%Y'); // -> '2013-05-01'
mysql> SELECT STR_TO_DATE('May 1, 2013','%M %d,%Y'); // -> '2013-05-01'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use php's [`strtotime`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) function.

> strtotime — Parse about any English
>   textual datetime description into a
>   Unix timestamp

You should check out the kind of format you can get to work with it for your string.

Answer (score 1):

> There is a problem : if data is *empty-12-2010" it print 2010-11-30.

Why?
Because strtotime is reading that as 00-12-2010, which doesn't exist, so it's converting it to the day before Dec 1, which is numerically Dec 0, or in reallife, Nov 30 !

Comment: OH! I wont check every day/month/year...its a waste of work ehhe! Any change to fix this?

Comment: Don't let the empty get to strtotime in the first place.  replace the data with 01 before it gets to strtotime

Comment: Uhm yeah, but in fact i couldnt know after if that's a real data or not.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by letting the user select '-' ? Does that mean "the whole month" or "doesn't matter" or what?

Comment: Example : if put `day` as `-` instead of `17` , `month=12` and `year=2010` I'll print just `December 2010`. Else, if the data is complete, `17-12-2010`. User can't know the exact date for some events :)

Comment: I would suggest storing the data in mysql not as datetime, but as varchar, Then you can just work with the string. Would that work for your application?

Comment: Yeah, in fact i ever done this before this topic. I hoped there is the possibility to manage this kind of data with DATETIME :)

Comment: Even if you store the data as varchar, you can still run queries against it like `"SELECT * FROM table WHERE eventdate >= '2010-12-01' AND eventdate <= '2010-12-31';`

Comment: Yeah, but its not so great store element that represent somethings in other that represent somethings others :)

Comment: So, in any case, there's another trouble : if a user also insert a date that is not real, when i convert it will change automatically. Not so great :) Hope there is a function like "check_if_date_is_real" :)

Answer (score 0):

Mysql does the convertion automatically. You can see accepted formats [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/datetime.html). But you should be aware of xxx and make mandatory that fields.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could use date(), using a format and string.

```
$mysqlDate = date( 'Y-m-d', $stringDate );
```

Comment: The second parameter has to be a timestamp not a string. See http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php