# Convert string "September 23" to DATETIME

Tags: mysql, datetime

I'm importing a column of strings with partial dates into a csv file.

During import, is there a way to convert strings with the format "September 23" into a DATETIME format, using the partial date to populate month, day and year, and the time of insert as the time?

Edit: I clarified the question, so the below answers aren't quite relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is ugly, but it works. The main problem was creating the year and time, and also dealing with single numeric values for the days of the month. `CONCAT_WS` is the glue in this scenario:

```
STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT_WS(',','September 5',YEAR(NOW()), TIME(NOW())), '%M %e, %Y, %T')
```

Returns:

```
2012-09-05 11:51:46
```

Answer (score 1):

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try DATE_FORMAT().

```
mysql> SELECT STR_TO_DATE('OCT 1, 2013','%M %d,%Y'); // -> '2013-10-01'
```

**STR_TO_DATE**-returns a DATETIME value if the format string contains both date and time parts, or a DATE or TIME value if the string contains only date or time parts. If the date, time, or datetime value extracted from str  is illegal, STR_TO_DATE()  returns NULL and produces a warning.

Refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4472170/mysql-php-how-to-convert-a-string-to-datetime) and this [also](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date).

Comment: Tried that. `STR_TO_DATE('September 4','%M, %d, %Y')` returns 0000-09-04. How can I grab the current year? Also, I need the time. Any ideas?

Comment: SELECT STR_TO_DATE( 'Jan 31,2008 23:52', '%M %d, %Y %H:%i' );
this is for Date with timestamp.